# Generate calendar with postgresql

Tags: date, calendar, postgresql-9.4, weekday

I'm trying to write query which shows calendar in format:

mon. thues. wen. th. fri. sat. sun.

First value in current week is always monday.

For instance, today is friday - 24-07-2015, so i need first value to be 20-07-2015 and the last one 26-07-2015

Until now, I came up with this:

```
SELECT 
    extract(DOW FROM r.e - s.a) w, 
    r.e  - s.a as dates
FROM generate_series(0,7,1) AS s(a),
     (SELECT CURRENT_DATE e) r
WHERE extract(DOW FROM CURRENT_DATE - s.a) >=1
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

and then I could sort it with distinct and then substract sunday in the same way. But maybe you can suggest some more elegant solution?

Basically I would like to find the date of closest monday and closest sunday.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ok, I've managed it:

WITH monday AS (
  SELECT
      r.e  - s.a as dow
  FROM generate_series(0,6,1) AS s(a),
     (SELECT CURRENT_DATE e) r
  WHERE extract(DOW FROM CURRENT_DATE - s.a) = 1
  ), sunday as (
  SELECT
     r.e  + s.a as dow
  FROM generate_series(0,6,1) AS s(a),
     (SELECT CURRENT_DATE e) r
  WHERE extract(DOW FROM CURRENT_DATE + s.a) = 0
), columns AS(

SELECT n::date
FROM generate_series((select dow from monday), (select dow from sunday), $$1 day$$) n
) SELECT n FROM columns;
```